# Get the current category inside the WordPress Loop

Tags: wordpress

I have this loop:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <li><h2 class="titles"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></li>
    <li><span class="post-date">Posted <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> at <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?></span><span class="post-cat">Filed under: <?php the_category(', ') ?> by <?php the_author(); ?></span></li>
    <li><p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p></li>
   <div class="voting"><?php DisplayVotes(get_the_ID()); ?></div>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

I only want to put this line `<div class="voting"><?php DisplayVotes(get_the_ID()); ?></div>` in only if the loop is referencing a certain category, ie. if (category== 'birthdays') then output this line.

I know how to do an if statement but what condition do i put in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [get_the_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) function

```
global $post;
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
var_dump($categories);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom theme for each category, 
Just call it "category-ID.php" and edit it as you want.
Check out this link http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates